# Efficient complex NHibernate Criteria query

Tags: c#, hibernate, nhibernate, hibernate-criteria, nhibernate-criteria

I have an `APVendor` class, which has a collection of `APInvoice` classes and a unique `Name`; each `APInvoice` has a collection of `APPayment` classes.  Each `APPayment` object references exactly one `BankAccount` class, a `ClearedDate`, an `Amount`, and a `CheckNumber` property.

With a bank statement that has a check record, let's say my *Bank of Foo* checking account, check **1111**, for the amount of **$1000.00**, I want to see if the payment exists in my persisted layer, and mark the `APPayment` object's `ClearedDate` property.

I can do this by querying the vendor, then querying the vendor's invoices, then looking for that check number written against the `BankAccount`, but I'm sure there's a much more efficient way to write this as one `Criteria` query.

Can someone help me with how that should look?  Here's how I would write the query in SQL to fetch the object graph I would need to work with:

```
select p.*, i.*, v.*
from appayments p
join bankaccounts a on p.bankaccountid = a.bankaccountid
join apinvoices i on i.invoiceid = p.invoiceid
join apvendors v on v.vendorid = i.vendorid
where a.bankaccountid = ????
and p.checknumber = ????
```

Comment: What exactly are you searching for? The APPayment which has a given CheckNumber and a given Amount? Any other restriction? Try to express your query in English, and the HQL query will follow.

Comment: @JBNizet, I expressed what I want in SQL...  it seems easier to explain than english.  Does it make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HQL query would be very similar to the SQL query:

```
select payment from APPayment payment
inner join payment.BankAccount bankAccount
left join fetch payment.Invoice invoice
left join fetch invoice.Vendor vendor
where bankAccount.id = :accountId
and payment.checkNumber = :checkNumber
```

The Criteria query is left as an exercise, but I don't see the poin tin using Criteria for such a static query.